# Добавление товара в корзину по клику на свою кнопку с помощью JS, сайт на WP

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress, woocommerce

я только учу JS, у меня интернет магазин на Wordpress по продаже билетов на футбол..

Как сделать так, чтобы с помощью js при **клике** на мою **кнопку** товар **добавлялся** в корзину?

Я пробовал сделать с помощью php, добавил 64 шорткода на вывод кнопки "Добавить в корзину" и получил некий опыт, а то есть скорость загрузки страницы 40 сек+

Помогите пожалуйста..

Comment: Учите ajax - https://wp-kama.ru/id_2018/ajax-v-wordpress.html

Comment: Хочу добавить то, что моя кнопка, это не кнопка по умолчанию от php, это именно мной добавленная кнопка..

И так же хочу добавить, что у меня дедлайн после завтра, я слишком много времени потратил на другой сайт, а сейчас понимаю, что я в попе и нужно что то делать с этим сайтом... ( я просто подумал, что с помощью шорткодов с кнопками у меня всё получиться.. )

Comment: Как раз для вашей кнопки нужен ajax. А шорткоды тут вообще ни при чём.

Comment: Данный вопрос уже поднимался участниками этого формуа.
Вот ссылка:[тык](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/405039/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B-%D0%B2-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5)

Comment: Если ИМ на ВП - значит используется какой-от плагин ИМ. Если плагин, то там это всё реализовано. В чём смысл плясок-то?

Comment: Я не нашёл информацию в поисковике, плагин тем более, да и плагин вряд ли помог бы мне. В этом интернет магазине на одной странице будет только порядком 3000 кнопок, а мне не просто нужно сделать, мне нужно сделать так, чтобы скорость загрузки не заходила за 6 сек

Comment: Приложите свои наработки, за Вас делать не будут